# JSON Path to check equals condition

Tags: json, apache-camel, jsonpath

I am a newbie to Json Path. I am using Apache camel along with the json path. I am trying to check the json path success to evaluate the value to true.

Json Message:

```
{
   "success": true,
   "errorMessage": ""
}
```

Camel Route:

```
<choice id="_choice1">
                    <when id="_when1">
                        <jsonpath suppressExceptions="false">[?($.success == true)]</jsonpath>
                        <log id="_log1" loggingLevel="INFO" message="success"/>

                    </when>
                    <otherwise id="_otherwise2">
                        <log id="_log4" loggingLevel="INFO" message="failure"/>
                    </otherwise>
                </choice>
```

It is always going to otherwise condition, I am not sure if success is evaluated correctly.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
?($.success == true)
```

If you are using Camel 2.19 or better, then you can use the easy syntax: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jsonpath/src/main/docs/jsonpath-language.adoc

And just say

```
success == true
```

Comment: Hi claus ,no luck i have tried it already and iam getting the exception Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Illegal character at position 1 expected '.' or '[

Answer (score 0):

Try to put root definition `$` and `@` like so:

```
<jsonpath suppressExceptions="false">$[?(@.success == true)]</jsonpath>
```

For more information, visit [Apacahe Camel JsonPath](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/languages/jsonpath-language.html) website.